# Saving MemoryStream to File produces 0 bytes

Tags: c#, filestream, using, memorystream

I'm using this code to write an MP3 MemoryStream to file:

```
using (var nSpeakStreamAsMp3 = new MemoryStream())
using (var nWavFileReader = new WaveFileReader(nSpeakStream))
using (var nMp3Writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(nSpeakStreamAsMp3, nWavFileReader.WaveFormat, LAMEPreset.STANDARD_FAST))
{
    nWavFileReader.CopyTo(nMp3Writer);

    string sPath = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\server\\bin\\mymp3.mp3";

    using (FileStream nFile = new FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
    {
        nSpeakStreamAsMp3.CopyTo(nFile);
    }

    sRet = (String.Concat("data:audio/mpeg;base64,", Convert.ToBase64String(nSpeakStreamAsMp3.ToArray())));
}

return sRet;
```

For some reason which I don't see, this produces a file of 0 bytes.
However, the MP3 stream is valid and does work. I'm passing it as a Base64String to a website, and I do hear it.

Where might be the error here?

Comment: Is there a flush() missing somewhere before you open up (and close) the inner FileStream?

Comment: @PhilCooper You mean "nMp3Writer"?

Comment: Adding "                        nMp3Writer.Flush();
                        nMp3Writer.Close();
                        nSpeakStreamAsMp3.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);" fixed it. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `nSpeakStreamAsMp3` is currently positioned at the *end* of the stream; you need to think like a VCR: be kind, rewind (`nSpeakStreamAsMp3.Position = 0;`) before you copy the value out again
2. make sure you flush `nMp3Writer`; if possible, close `nMp3Writer` completely